# Oracle, two tables with different attributes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to find the total profit for a month.

For example I have two tables, one table `transactions` has the attribute `agreedprice`, the other table called `car` has an attribute called `pricepurchased`. How can I display these two tables side by side?

I've tried all types of joins however it's only giving me matching values between the two. I want to see the `agreedprice` and the `pricepurchased` in my SQL file, the price purchased never meets the `agreedprice` so for every statement I've done it only gives me one side.

Comment: In order to join two SQL tables, you need some common link between them.  It is hard to recommend what that should be in your case unless you can update your post with the schema for your two tables, but best practice is that you have a column in common between the two tables.  Then your join is linking all or parts of the two tables together using that column in each as the connection point.

Comment: Include structure of both tables and some sample data, but @steveklein right.  Some common value should exist in both tables, like carID in table transactions and in car table in order to get them to relate correctly together.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table structure Something like this will work if you have a common field in both tables (e.g. carid)

```
SELECT c.carid, t.agreedprice, c.pricepurchased
FROM car c
INNER JOIN transactions t ON c.carid = t.carid
```

Comment: thanks alot, their was a common attribute VIN, i got it to then display the purchasedprice and then the agreedprice. i got to this point so far select to_char(dateofsale,'mon')as month,c.vin,SUM(st.agreedprice-c.purchasedprice)
from car c
inner join salestransaction st on c.vin=st.vin just have to figure out how to get it to display this now. but im sure ill figure it out

Comment: select distinct to_char(dateofsale,'MON') as month,c.vin,sum(st.agreedprice-c.purchasedprice) AS PROFITS
from car c
inner join salestransaction st on c.vin=st.vin
where to_char(dateofsale,'YYYY')='2014'
group by to_char(dateofsale,'MON'),c.vin; its looking like that but i keep getting multiple months eg, about 3 January records display whereas i just want one that combines all for the month of jan or feb etc.